# Python delete item from a dictionary when double iterating

Tags: python, loops, dictionary, key

I want to delet items from a dict where the value is a number and the key a datetime:
Conditions:
if the value is the same i want to delete all items with the same value within 1h

```
    #del duplicates within 60min
    for formatted_key in list(formatted_dict.keys()):
        for temp_key in list(formatted_dict.keys()):
            print("formatted_key:", formatted_key)
            print("temp_key:", temp_key)
            if(formatted_dict[formatted_key]==formatted_dict[temp_key]):
                if(temp_key!=formatted_key):
                    td=timedelta(minutes = 60)
                    new_key=formatted_key+td
                    if (new_key>temp_key):
                        del formatted_dict[temp_key]
                        print("key to delet:", temp_key)
                        for key,value in formatted_dict.items():
                            print(key,value)
```

the output i get till the error:

```
**test data dict:**
2022-10-25 08:14:08.820000 var301533
2022-10-25 08:16:12.286000 var301533
2022-10-25 08:17:05.067000 var003907
2022-10-25 08:19:04.422000 var003907
2022-10-25 08:20:05.021000 var301504
2022-10-25 08:23:04.526000 var301504
2022-10-25 08:23:14.204000 var301504

**the for loops:**
formatted_key: 2022-10-25 08:14:08.820000
temp_key: 2022-10-25 08:14:08.820000
formatted_key: 2022-10-25 08:14:08.820000
temp_key: 2022-10-25 08:16:12.286000
key to delet: 2022-10-25 08:16:12.286000

**key and value gets deleted**
2022-10-25 08:14:08.820000 var301533
2022-10-25 08:17:05.067000 var003907
2022-10-25 08:19:04.422000 var003907
2022-10-25 08:20:05.021000 var301504
2022-10-25 08:23:04.526000 var301504
2022-10-25 08:23:14.204000 var301504

formatted_key: 2022-10-25 08:14:08.820000
temp_key: 2022-10-25 08:17:05.067000
formatted_key: 2022-10-25 08:14:08.820000
temp_key: 2022-10-25 08:19:04.422000
formatted_key: 2022-10-25 08:14:08.820000
temp_key: 2022-10-25 08:20:05.021000
formatted_key: 2022-10-25 08:14:08.820000
temp_key: 2022-10-25 08:23:04.526000
formatted_key: 2022-10-25 08:14:08.820000
temp_key: 2022-10-25 08:23:14.204000
formatted_key: 2022-10-25 08:16:12.286000
temp_key: 2022-10-25 08:14:08.820000
```

the right key/value gets deleted which you can see in the output but the problem is that the outer for-loop still gets the deleted key but dont find the deleted value.

key error but i dont have a solution to the problem:

```
    if(formatted_dict[formatted_key]==formatted_dict[temp_key]):
KeyError: datetime.datetime(2022, 10, 25, 8, 16, 12, 286000)
```

Expected output:

```
**final dict:**
2022-10-25 08:14:08.820000 var301533
2022-10-25 08:17:05.067000 var003907
2022-10-25 08:20:05.021000 var301504
```

Comment: "delete all items with the same value within 1h" Within one hour of what? Please show sample dictionary data and expected output

Comment: Have you considered the case of entries with same value repeated every half an hour over the time span of several hours? Any of them are within one hour to the next one, but the first one is many hours before the last one. Which ones would you like to delete then???

Comment: this is actually 2 questions:  [1] `delete items from a dict where the value is a number and the key a datetime`, [2] `f the value is the same i want to delete all items with the same value within 1h`....  which one are you struggling with ?

Comment: You can find the dict i want to process in the output
its a test data dict and in the end all duplicates have to be deleted like:
2022-10-25 08:14:08.820000 var301533
2022-10-25 08:17:05.067000 var003907
2022-10-25 08:20:05.021000 var301504

Comment: It is generally a bad idea to delete items of objects within a loop in which you use the items of these objects. Consider to totally rewrite your code and use another approach (e.g. sorting the dictionary entries by value and key first).

Comment: @OldBill have reworked the post. -->
an hour in which the variable reappears again

Comment: @Claudio i dont know a better way to solve it

Comment: @D.L no the program already works to the point where we jump to the outer loop again.
[2] dont know how to get around the keyerror

Comment: @Max Are the keys in the input dictionary (*formatted_dict*) guaranteed to be in ascending order?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A *not recommended change* (better rewrite your code using another approach) in order to avoid a KeyError would be to use:

```
if( formatted_key in formatted_dict and temp_key in formatted_dict and formatted_dict[formatted_key]==formatted_dict[temp_key]):
```

and

```
if temp_key in formatted_dict: del formatted_dict[temp_key]
```

(another approach to avoid dictionary KeyError can be usage of Pythons `try: ... except ...:` construct)

Comment: thank you. it worked using only the first line which should be fine.